# Default value for date_helper in formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

As basic as it sounds, I can't make the date_helper default to a date, as in:

```
- semantic_form_for resource do |f|
  - f.inputs do
    = f.input :issued_on, :default => Date.today
  = f.buttons
```

The above just renders blank columns if resource does not have a date.

Would appreciate any pointer on what I'm possibly doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've recently implemented a :selected option against all :select, :radio and :check_boxes inputs in Formtastic, so it'll be in the next patch release (0.9.5) or 1.0.  Until then, the advice to create an after_initialize or to set the default in the controller is good advice, however I do think that sometimes the best person to decide on the default value is the *designer*, who may not be comfortable the controllers or models, which is why we added this as part of the Formtastic DSL.

Comment: The `:selected` option is [deprecated](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/wiki/Deprecation-of-%3Aselected-option) now, so we'll soon be back to square one.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the default on the object itself on your controller

```
def edit
  @resource = Resource.find(params[:id])
  @resource.issued_on ||= Date.today
end
```

Comment: +1, beat me by a couple minutes. I think this way is the best practice.

Comment: moving defaults to the controller, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

You should define after_initialize in the model. If an after_initialize method is defined in your model it gets called as a callback to new, create, find and any other methods that generate instances of your model.

Ideally you'd want to define it like this:

```
class resource < ActiveRecord::Base

  def after_initialize
    @issued_on ||= Date.today
  end
  ...
end
```

Then your view would look like this:

```
- semantic_form_for resource do |f|
  - f.inputs do
    = f.input :issued_on
  = f.buttons
```

This will also guard against nil errors if you find a record that doesn't have those fields set. However, that shouldn't happen unless you create a record directly without ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

you can put following in your model file

```
def after_initialize
    self.start ||= Date.today
    self.token ||= SecureRandom.hex(4)
    self.active ||= true
end
```

the above issued

```
@issued_on ||= Date.today
```

has not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I like the following way

```
after_initialize :set_issued_on

def set_issued_on
  @issued_on||=Date.today
end
```

Bit longer, but nice and clear