# ActiveRecord: Doesnt call after_initialize when method name is passed as a symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I noticed that Rails doesn't trigger `after_initialize` callback when the callback symbol is passed as input.

The code below doesn't work.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :init_data

  def init_data
    puts "In init_data"
  end

end
```

The code below works.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def after_initialize 
    init_data
  end

  def init_data
    puts "In init_data"
  end
end
```

Can somebody explain this behavior?

**Note 1**

The ActiveRecord [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) says the following about `after_initialize`:

```
Unlike all the other callbacks, after_find and after_initialize will 
only be run if an explicit implementation is defined (def after_find). 
In that case, all of the callback types will be called.
```

Though it is stated that after_initialize requires explicit implementation, I find the second sentence in the above paragraph ambiguous, i.e. `In that case, all of 
    the callback types will be called.` What is `all of the call back types`?

The code sample in the documentation has an example that doesn't use explicit implementation:

```
after_initialize EncryptionWrapper.new
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find), you cannot use the macro-style class methods for the `after_initialize` or `after_find` callbacks:

> The after_initialize and after_find
>   callbacks are a bit different from the
>   others. They have no before_*
>   counterparts, and the only way to
>   register them is by defining them as
>   regular methods. If you try to
>   register after_initialize or
>   after_find using macro-style class
>   methods, they will just be ignored.
>   This behaviour is due to performance
>   reasons, since after_initialize and
>   after_find will both be called for
>   each record found in the database,
>   significantly slowing down the
>   queries.

In short, you have to define an `after_initialize` instance method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def after_initialize
    do_stuff
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that methods invoked by symbol need to be protected or private.

Edit: Yep, here's the [Rails 3 documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html):

> The method reference callbacks work by specifying a protected or private method available in the object

Comment: I tried making my callback method private, and I still got the same behavior.